# PayPal Virtual Terminal Questions

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Firstly, how do I access the Virtual Terminal with my sandbox account?  I have tried going to the My Selling Tools area, but it never loads.  I thought maybe it was Chrome, so I tried IE10 and FireFox.  IE10 can't load the PayPal developer page at all, and FireFox gets exactly as far as Chrome does.

Secondly, using Virtual Terminal, is there a way to customize the fields?  We have a few dozen sites that will be using the main account, but we want to be able to differentiate the payments via site.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different ways you can access the Virtual Terminal from within your sandbox.  The most direct way would be once you are signed in, on the home page towards the middle of the page there should be a section for "Tool".  In this section you should see a link for Virtual Terminal.  If you click this link it will take you to the Virtual Terminal.

As for your second question, you would not be able to customize the Virtual Terminal page.  If you are looking for a customized look, you would want to build your own interface the way that you are wanting it to look.  Then behind the scenes you would have that page use the DoDirectPayment API when you fill in the customers information and hit submit.  This would give you an interface similar to the Virtual Terminal, and would work just like the Virtual Terminal.

Comment: I do not have a section called "Tool" anywhere on the page.  As mentioned, if I expand the Profile button I have a "My Selling Tools", but it does not load.

Comment: Can you provide me with the email address to your test sandbox seller account and i will check it to make sure that it is set up correctly and is of the right type of an account.

Comment: The account did not have Website Payments Pro enabled on it.  I have enabled this on the account, and you should see the links for Virtual Terminal within the account now.

Comment: Yes, I have Virtual Terminal now.  Thanks :)